# Add view under the tabgroup

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup backgroundColor="white" id="mainTabGroup">
        <Tab id="byFav" title="fav" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window title='fav'>
                <TableView id="tableByFav" />
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="byLatest" title="latest" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window title='latest'>
                <TableView id="tableByLatest" />
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Currently I have tabgroup which has two tab.

I am planning to add view at the bottom of the screen height=50 width=100%.

This view must be still however tab changes.

I have tried this

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup backgroundColor="white" id="mainTabGroup">
    .
    .
    .
    </TabGroup>
    <view>
    </view>
</Alloy>
```

or this.

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup backgroundColor="white" id="mainTabGroup">
    .
    .
    .
    </TabGroup>
    <window>
    </window>
</Alloy>
```

But it shows the message like this

```
invalid method (createwindow) passed to UIModule
```

I might not understand the basic thought of alloy.

Is it possible to add the view under the tablegroup?

If not, I would like to add the fixed view in each tab.

Does anyone give me the first hint?

I am suffering from the shortage of alloy documents.

Comment: Plz explain in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do such thing, because TabGroup uses windows and a "Window" in Alloy means the entire screen. I suggest making another view/controller (yourView) for your bottom view and then require it in all your tabs.

```
<Alloy>
<TabGroup backgroundColor="white" id="mainTabGroup">
    <Tab id="byFav" title="fav" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
        <Window title='fav'>
            <TableView id="tableByFav" />
            <Require type="view" src="yourView"/>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
    <Tab id="byLatest" title="latest" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
        <Window title='latest'>
            <TableView id="tableByLatest" />
            <Require type="view" src="yourView"/>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</TabGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks I understand it is a bit complex concept for me,I will keep learning